# Generic method of mapping variables from 1 class to another

Tags: java, generics

Coming from C++ and currently employed in a Java environment, I was wondering how I would be able to create a mapping of void* and void* in Java in order to create a generic mapping from A to B and from B to A. I am aware that Java doesn't have pointers and references the way C++ does, but am failing to find a method that would still allow this.

An example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
public class A{
    @GenericMapping(1)
    private Integer temp1;
}

public class B{
    @GenericMapping(1)
    private Integer temp2;
}

public class Mapper{
    private List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> mapping;
    public void map(Object ObjectOfAnyClassButLetsAssumeA, Object ObjectOfAnyClassButLetsAssumeB){
        // Get all parameters with GenericMapping above it, get its value
        // and match the corresponding value with the value of B
        // Resulting in A.temp1 = B.temp2;
    }
}
```

However, if possible I'd rather create a map (like map[A.temp1] = B.temp2) in order to avoid using the @GenericMapping, seeing as that would allow me to not modify the class in any way and still facilitate its mapping.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do.  You have class names that are the same as parameter names.  Your parameters are declared as having type `Object`; are they supposed to have types `A` and `B`?  What is `mapping`, since you don't use it at all?  I suspect you need to learn some Java basics first, because there is probably a much simpler way to do whatever it is you're trying to do instead of trying to emulate how you did things in C++.

Comment: They're supposed to have types Object, since the mapping could be of any class. I named them A and B to indicate I intended to call them with objects of class A and B. As for my Java basics, I've been working professionally in Java for over a year, and passed my Java Certification with a near-100%... Although I agree it could be I'm mis-telling my intentions (gotta love autism).

Comment: We get a lot of questions from Java programmers who don't fully understand how to use Java's OO concepts to model the problem they're trying to solve, so they try to solve their problems with other mechanisms.  You haven't provided a good idea of what you want the end result to be or how you're going to use this thing you're trying to develop (even though your edit helps a little bit), so it was hard for me to tell that this wasn't that kind of new Java programmer question.  I apologize for that........

Comment: But I still would need more information to tell whether this is the right approach to the problem.  Generally, using things like annotations and reflection is needed only for those developing frameworks like Spring, or even smaller frameworks used by a team, but it shouldn't be necessary to solve a problem within one application.

Comment: The issue is that we have about 4 different models right now, with each implementation of an application having its own mapping. I would like to try and solve having multiple mappings using a generic mapping system. The end result I would like to be a simple mapping of Model1_ObjectA.test1 = Model2_ObjectA.test1 = Model3_ObjectX.test13
which would allow us to completely avoid the separate mapping implementations per model / application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you want to do here and you can accomplish it with some metadata and Java 8's Lambdas.

What we do is set up a helper class that contains all mappings identified by class and IDs (analogous to your @GenericMapping but without actually annotating the classes) and containing methods for setting and getting the value. It's important that all mappings for the same ID have the same value type or a ClassCastException may be thrown when transferring values.

My example uses three classes where not all mappings apply to all classes.

Here's the code:

```
public class GenericMappingDemo {

    static class A {
        private Integer integerA;
        private String stringA;
        private Float floatA;

        public A(final Integer integerA, final String stringA, final Float floatA) {
            this.integerA = integerA;
            this.stringA = stringA;
            this.floatA = floatA;
        }

        public Integer getIntegerA() {
            return integerA;
        }

        public void setIntegerA(final Integer integerA) {
            this.integerA = integerA;
        }

        public String getStringA() {
            return stringA;
        }

        public void setStringA(final String stringA) {
            this.stringA = stringA;
        }

        public Float getFloatA() {
            return floatA;
        }

        public void setFloatA(final Float floatA) {
            this.floatA = floatA;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "A{integerA=" + integerA + ", stringA='" + stringA + "', floatA=" + floatA + '}';
        }
    }

    static class B {
        private Integer integerB;
        private String stringB;

        public Integer getIntegerB() {
            return integerB;
        }

        public void setIntegerB(final Integer integerB) {
            this.integerB = integerB;
        }

        public String getStringB() {
            return stringB;
        }

        public void setStringB(final String stringB) {
            this.stringB = stringB;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "B{integerB=" + integerB + ", stringB='" + stringB + '\'' + '}';
        }
    }

    static class C {
        private Float floatC;
        private String stringC;

        public Float getFloatC() {
            return floatC;
        }

        public void setFloatC(final Float floatC) {
            this.floatC = floatC;
        }

        public String getStringC() {
            return stringC;
        }

        public void setStringC(final String stringC) {
            this.stringC = stringC;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "C{floatC=" + floatC + ", stringC='" + stringC + "'}";
        }
    }

    static class GenericMapping<C, T> {
        final int id;
        final Class<C> type;
        final Function<C, T> getter;
        final BiConsumer<C, T> setter;

        public GenericMapping(final int id,
                final Class<C> type,
                final Function<C, T> getter,
                final BiConsumer<C, T> setter) {
            this.id = id;
            this.type = type;
            this.getter = getter;
            this.setter = setter;
        }
    }

    static class Mapper {
        // All mappings by class and id
        private final Map<Class<?>, Map<Integer, GenericMapping<?, ?>>> mappings
                = new HashMap<>();

        public void addMapping(GenericMapping<?, ?> mapping) {
            mappings.computeIfAbsent(mapping.type,
                    c -> new TreeMap<>()).put(mapping.id, mapping);
        }

        /**
         * Map values from one object to another,
         * using any mapping ids that apply to both classes
         * @param from The object to transfer values from
         * @param to The object to transfer values to
         */
        public <From, To> void map(From from, To to) {
            Map<Integer, GenericMapping<?, ?>> getters
                    = mappings.get(from.getClass());
            Map<Integer, GenericMapping<?, ?>> setters
                    = mappings.get(to.getClass());
            if (getters == null || setters == null) {
                // Nothing to do
                return;
            }

            // Create a set with the ids in both getters and
            // setters, i.e. the mappings that apply
            Set<Integer> ids = new HashSet<>(getters.keySet());
            ids.retainAll(setters.keySet());

            // Transfer all mappings
            for (Integer id : ids) {
                GenericMapping<From, ?> getter
                        = (GenericMapping<From, ?>) getters.get(id);
                GenericMapping<To, ?> setter
                        = (GenericMapping<To, ?>) setters.get(id);
                transfer(from, to, getter, setter);
            }
        }

        private <From, To, V> void transfer(final From from,
                final To to, final GenericMapping<From, ?> getter,
                final GenericMapping<To, V> setter) {
            // This will throw an exception if the mappings are invalid
            final V value = (V) getter.getter.apply(from);
            setter.setter.accept(to, value);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Mapper mapper = new Mapper();

        // Mapping definition for class A
        mapper.addMapping(new GenericMapping<>(1, A.class,
                A::getIntegerA, A::setIntegerA));
        mapper.addMapping(new GenericMapping<>(2, A.class,
                A::getStringA, A::setStringA));
        mapper.addMapping(new GenericMapping<>(3, A.class,
                A::getFloatA, A::setFloatA));

        // Mapping definition for class B
        mapper.addMapping(new GenericMapping<>(1, B.class,
                B::getIntegerB, B::setIntegerB));
        mapper.addMapping(new GenericMapping<>(2, B.class,
                B::getStringB, B::setStringB));

        // Mapping definition for class C
        mapper.addMapping(new GenericMapping<>(2, C.class,
                C::getStringC, C::setStringC));
        mapper.addMapping(new GenericMapping<>(3, C.class,
                C::getFloatC, C::setFloatC));

        // Use the mappings
        A a = new A(7, "foo", 3.7f);
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();

        System.out.printf("A before map: %s%n", a);
        System.out.printf("B before map: %s%n", b);
        System.out.printf("C before map: %s%n", c);

        // This will transfer a.integerA to b.integerB and a.stringA to b.stringB
        mapper.map(a, b);
        // This will transfer a.stringA to c.stringC and a.floatA to c.floatC
        mapper.map(a, c);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("A after map: %s%n", a);
        System.out.printf("B after map: %s%n", b);
        System.out.printf("C after map: %s%n", c);
    }
}
```

And the result after running it:

```
A before map: A{integerA=7, stringA='foo', floatA=3.7}
B before map: B{integerB=null, stringB='null'}
C before map: C{floatC=null, stringC='null'}

A after map: A{integerA=7, stringA='foo', floatA=3.7}
B after map: B{integerB=7, stringB='foo'}
C after map: C{floatC=3.7, stringC='foo'}
```

## Java 7

The same general solution can be used for Java 7, but it will be a lot more verbose. Since Java 7 doesn't have the functional interfaces `Function<U, V>` and `BiConsumer<U, V>` you'll need to define these yourself, which isn't that much trouble. It could be argued that they should be defined in Java 8 too so interface and method names makes more sense (e.g. `Getter.get` and `Setter.set`).

The big thing is the mapping definitions which will have to use anonymous classes instead of lambdas - lambdas is mostly syntactic sugar for anonymous classes with only one method anyways, but they make the code a lot more readable.

The mapping for a.integerA will look like this in Java 7:

```
mapper.addMapping(new GenericMapping<>(1, A.class,
        new Function<A, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer apply(final A a1) {
                return a1.getIntegerA();
            }
        },
        new BiConsumer<A, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(final A a1, final Integer integerA) {
                a1.setIntegerA(integerA);
            }
        }));
```

Comment: This looks amazing! :)
I marked it as answer seeing as it perfectly answers my question, but I do have a question: What would need to be changed in order to make this work using Java 7 (Or is this not possible at all)? Unfortunately the company's code hasn't gone to Java 8 yet..

Comment: Thanks. I updated with a section on Java 7. Basically you'll just need to define the `Function` and `BiConsumer` interfaces and expand the lambdas into anonymous classes

Comment: You're a hero :D

Answer (score 1):

You could also have a look at Apache Commons BeanUtils, which also have a quite sophisticated, although explicit (not Annotation-based), Converter API:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/Converter.html

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/ConvertUtilsBean.html